# Automatic Logout On Close Tab/Browser - Blazor Server Side

Tags: c#, session, blazor, blazor-server-side, logout

Im Working on a Blazor Server Side app with Identity, and i want to end session when user close Tab / Browser, i try using the following

```
services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Expiration = DateTime.MaxValue;
        });
```

But it didn't work. I think It's probably a misunderstanding of concepts from my part, would appreciate any help! Or if they need more data to Provide, just tell me!

Comment: you should implement a CircuitHandler for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.server.circuits.circuithandler?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: here is a sample project:  https://github.com/nagytam/BlazorCircuitHandler